# UIButton image asynchronously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a bunch of UIButton in a UIScrollView and each UIButton takes an image from a URL. What is the easiest way so that the image will be loaded asynchronously?

For example, the usual way is:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but this blocks the UI, I don't want it to

Comment: I think u need to replace bunch of button with asynchImageview, using asynchImageview you can get touch event each image view without affecting other asynchView. and asynch solve issues of blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImag) withObject:nil];
```

In loadImage function load the image from url and then assign it to the button.
I am not sure this will work for you...As I am a beginner in objective C development

Comment: nope.. you can't set any UI stuff not from the main thread, besides in this case loadImage needs to take the button as a parameter

Comment: This will work just fine, provided you call back to the main thread when the image has loaded to do the actual setting.

Comment: @JoshCaswell then we would need to pass in the UIButton that the image we want to set along with the URL in the loadImage method.. how do you do that? If you can provide a code for that I'd accept the answer

Comment: @aher: Pass the URL as the `withObject` argument of the `performSelector...` call. Then in the `loadImage` method, return the image data to the main thread with `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:`

Comment: @JohnCaswell I know the performSelectorOnMainThread method, but we need the button to be set the image here.. how do I get that in the loadImage method? You'd basically have to encapsulate that into the dictionary and pass it to the withObject right?

Answer (score 0):

Try with an NSInvocationOperation, make an synchronous request for each image button... Pass the button as parameter, something like this i mean...

Init the operation queue (maybe on init):

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

start the operation invocation for each button...

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                        selector:@selector(getImageFromURL:) 
                                                                          object:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://getMyImage.com/resource.jpg", @"url", button, @"button", nil]];

[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

this can be your `getImageFromURL:` selector

```
- (void) getImageFromURL:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLFromString:[dict objectForKey:@"url"]];
    UIButton *button = [dict objectForKey:@"button"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    // Finally set the button image and release image ...
    [pool drain];
}
```

Don't forget release queue on dealloc...

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is alright, if you block while loading one single image? The problem is that you have many of them? If so, then I would do like this (no threads needed):

```
#define DELAY 0.1 // you may set it to 0 as well

    ...
    [self performSelector:@selector(setupButton:)
               withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
               afterDelay:DELAY];
    ...

-(void)setupButton:(NSNumber*)count
{
    UIButton *button = [self buttonFromMyScrollViewWithCount:count.intValue];
    [button setImage:...];
    if (count.intValue < self.numberOfButtonsInMyScrollView)
        [self performSelector:@selector(setupButton:)
                   withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count.intValue + 1]
                   afterDelay:DELAY];
}
```